# Xcode cannot find one CocoaPod module, but has no issues with others

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

I have a Podfile with these dependencies

```
  pod 'Firebase'
  pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
  pod 'Gloss', '~> 0.7'
```

I have installed everything with `pod install`. I have no issues using the Firebase modules, but Xcode cannot find the Gloss module. I am using the .xcworkspace file and not the project file. In the Pods/Products folder I can see a Gloss.framework file and I've tried adding this file to the linked frameworks portion of the project configuration, but it has no effect.

This is the entire Podfile

```
 target 'Status App' do
  # Comment this line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for Status App
  pod 'Firebase'
  pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
  pod 'Gloss', '~> 0.7'
  target 'Status AppTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

  target 'Status AppUITests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end
```

Comment: Can you post your Podfile? (I'm thinking you don't have the `use frameworks`.)

Comment: I posted my podfile and use_frameworks! is in there.